# Bot reading other users added reaction

Tags: python, discord.py

I made a small blackjack game with a hit/stand/double. Everything is working fine except the bot reads other added reaction by other users..

- If someone reacted to hit and the author reacted to stand, bot will process the hit first then process the stand.
- If someone reacted to stand and author reacted to hit, bot will process the hit then it would process the stand.
- If someone reacted to stand and author reacted to double, bot will only process the stand.

Here's my code:

```
@commands.command(name='bj')
async def blackjack(self, ctx, bet: int):
        hit = ":red_circle:"
        stand = ":blue_circle:"
        double = ":green_circle:"
        
        msg = await ctx.send('Test')
        await msg.add_reaction(HIT)
        await msg.add_reaction(STAND)
        await msg.add_reaction(DOUBLE)

        self.hit = False
        self.stand = False
        self.double = False

        def check(reaction, user):
            if str(reaction.emoji) == hit:
                self.hit = True
                return user == ctx.author and str(reaction.message) == str(msg)
            elif str(reaction.emoji) == stand:
                self.stand = True
                return user == ctx.author and str(reaction.message) == str(msg)
            elif str(reaction.emoji) == double:
                self.double = True
                return user == ctx.author and str(reaction.message) == str(msg)

        while True:
            try:
                reaction = await self.client.wait_for(
                    "reaction_add", check=check, timeout=20
                )

                if reaction and hit:
                    # Do hit things
                    self.hit = False
                    await ctx.send('hit clicked')
                    break

                elif reaction and stand:
                    # Do stand things
                    self.stand = False
                    await ctx.send('stand clicked')
                    break

                elif reaction and double:
                    # Do double things
                    self.double = False
                    await ctx.send('double clicked')
                    break

            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                # Do things
                await ctx.send('afk')
                break
```

Here's a photo of what it looks like, other user added reaction to hit and author message reacted to stand. It sent hit instead of the stand.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you share the full command code? I can't do testing with that code alone.

Comment: @Lemon.py edited it and added a picture.

Comment: is the code you provided inside of an async function?

Comment: Yup inside of async edited it again.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by changing my def check. Thanks for the replies.